# Create API in Groovy for Java

Tags: java, groovy

I'm need to create an api for what will be a suite of primarily java applications.  I need to do this quickly however, and at the moment I'm most comfortable writing in groovy.  My question is, can I create this api in groovy, and use it in java applications without any special hoops?

That is, can I create a jar from my groovy classes and methods, and have the java applications use this jar as though it were created in java?

Comment: I don't think so.  I imagine creating a collection of classes written in groovy, so not a traditional "script".

Comment: I'd really like it if someone would explain why they are down-voting this.  I'll gladly fix the question given some useful feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just compile using gradle, ant, whatever, to generate a jar. The resulting jar will depend on Groovy runtime jar and modules, if any. Groovy compiles to bytecode, so Java doesn't really know the differente. Only dynamic stuff won't work.

MyLib.groovy:

```
class MyLib {
  def string

  MyLib(string) { 
    this.string = string 
  }

  String yell() { 
    string.toUpperCase() + "!!!" 
  }
}
```

Compiled:

```
$ groovyc MyLib.groovy
```

Writing the Java class which uses the Groovy one, TestMyLib.java:

```
public class TestMyLib {
  public static void main(String[] args ) {
    MyLib my = new MyLib("john doe");
    System.out.println(my.yell()); // prints JOHN DOE!!!
  }
}
```

Compiling:

```
$ javac TestMyLib.java
```

And execution:

```
$ java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.1.8.jar:. TestMyLib
JOHN DOE!!!
```